# DDD in PHP -> Projector -> Where and when should the register method be called of the projector?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cqrs, domain-events

I'm currently reading about projections from the book [DDD in PHP](https://leanpub.com/ddd-in-php/) and I'm confused when and where to call the register method from the projector class.

**Flow:** CreateNewTaskRequest -> CreateNewTaskService -> Task::writeFromNew() -> PDOTaskRepository.

At the end of the save method of the PDOTaskRepository, the project method of the projector gets called, which in turn will call the project method of all the registered projections that are listening for the given domain events.

But where and when do I register projections to the projector?

```
class PDOTaskRepository implements TaskRepository
{
    private $projector;

    public function __construct(Projector $projector)
    {
        $this->projector = $projector;
    }

    public function save(Task $task)
    {
        // Code to save in DB


        $this->projector->project($task->recordedEvents());
    }
}


class Projector
{
    /**
     * @var Projection[]
     */
    private $projections = [];


    /**
     * @param Projection[] $projections
     */
    public function register(array $projections)
    {
        foreach ($projections as $projection) {
            $this->projections[$projection->listensTo()] = $projection;
        }
    }

    public function project(array $events)
    {
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            if (isset($this->projections[get_class($event)])) {
                $this->projections[get_class($event)]->project($event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing you're looking for is pub/sub pattern.

Comment: Are these synchronous projections?

Comment: @plalx yes it's synchronous

Answer (score 2):

There's a multitude of ways to do that. However, given that your `Projector` class is not thread-safe, you must do it somewhere there is no contention. I'd do it in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) of my application, either directly or indirectly by leveraging an application-starting hook if any.

Also, to minimize the risk of someone misusing the `register` function of the `Projector` I'd probably just pass in all projections when constructing the `Projector` class. That eliminates the risk of someone calling `register` at a later time possibly creating contention with an ongoing `project` operation.